# Am I the only one seeing an empty inbox

Tags: bug, status-completed, global-inbox

I had two new messages in my inbox, but when I tried to view it I just saw a blank box.  Now I can't get anything but a blank box to show (well, except for the little black progress dots that appear for a moment).

I've tried restarting my browser (Firefox), and I've tried using another browser (Chrome), but nothing helps.  I've seen this behavior since 9pm PST this morning; am I the only one?

Comment: [the sysadmins are having fun](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1017470#1017470)

Comment: Yes, you are the only one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will fix itself given some time.

We switched our load balancers this weekend, and this morning one of the old ones decided it wasn't riding into the sunset without a fight.

Fallout from that affected inbox loading, and as a consequence anybody who tried to load their inbox for the first time today ended up with an empty inbox.  New items will still go into your inbox, and once the "empty" one falls out of cache historical items will be available again.

Comment: Any idea of how long the site cache lives? I'm wondering if I have hours or days before I can find out what my messages were.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie - the cache can live for up to a day; you should be able to see old messages on your [network profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/current) inbox tab, I want to say that bypasses the cache.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like the network profile inbox is the same, but up to a day isn't that long to hold on for.