# My inbox suddenly emptied on SO

Tags: bug, notifications, global-inbox

Just finished answering a question when I saw a notification in my inbox. Upon opening it, all of my notifications were gone. Checked with browsers I don't usually use and ones that have an incognito mode and they're all empty. Visiting other SE sites (other than Meta) shows the same issue, but I can see my notifications here. I've seen a few other topics with this question, however I [haven't been away](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67498/the-so-global-inbox-is-empty-sometimes) and didn't see anything about [server maintenance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139148/am-i-the-only-one-seeing-an-empty-inbox). Is it just me?

> [image]

**July 18<sup>th</sup> update**: happens again for at least five hours now, maybe more. The inbox in Stack Exchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ is empty, while in the inbox tab of my network profile it's fine and showing all items. Also worth to mention that the raw request to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/inbox/genuwine returns `[]`.

Comment: Can't reproduce in Chrome 27: All of my inbox items are present and accounted for.

Comment: I'm seeing exactly the same effect as the OP.

Comment: ditto. it only happens on the main site. meta is fine.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins try on the main site.

Comment: doing the same for me in IE8 and FF.

Comment: @DanielA.White Did, with the same results. (That's how I got notification of your comment here. :) )

Comment: I'll add that I looked at my network activity and I can see the Ajax call to /inbox/genuwine, but the response is "[]".

Comment: Not just you, me too. But it's back now.

Comment: @DanielFischer - still MIA for me.

Comment: It's gone AWOL again for me :( Seems I tested it in just the split second it was there.

Comment: Looks like I picked the wrong week to quit sniffing glue

Comment: And it's back once more. Try refreshing the page, and then look at the inbox. That just worked for me. Could be a hiccup with the websockets?

Comment: @DanielFischer - no joy

Comment: +1, I actually tried to close the box and it took me a second to realize it's a picture.

Comment: +1. Waiting for it to get back.

Comment: Have you tried to log on and log back?